# Understanding the filterM function

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I am learning about the `filterM` function in the book "Learn You a Haskell for Great Good!" by Miran Lipovaca. For the following example:

```
keepSmall :: Int -> Writer [String] Bool
keepSmall x
   | x < 4 = do
       tell ["Keeping " ++ show x]
       return True
   | otherwise = do
      tell [show x ++ " is too large, throwing it away"]
      return False
```

The result obtained from using this function with `filterM` is the following:

```
> runWriter $ filterM keepSmall [9,1,5,2,10,3]
([1,2,3],["9 is too large, throwing it away","Keeping 1","5 is too large, 
throwing it away","Keeping 2","10 is too large, throwing it away","Keeping 3"])
```

Regarding the type of the result of `filterM`, I know that `filterM` has the following type declaration:

```
filterM :: (Monad m) => (a -> m Bool) -> [a] -> m [a]
```

Since the monad used for this example is `Writer [String]`, would the type of the list resulting from `filterM` be `Writer [String] [Int]`? If this is the case, is this why the result type is `([Int], [String])`, since `Writer w a` is equivalent to the tuple `(a,w)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because of the type of `runWriter`

```
runWriter :: Writer w a -> (a, w)
```

from Hoogle, it literally just unwrap a writer computation as a (result, output) pair. That's why you got the result in a pair.

A little example, just to see how it works in other context:

```
runWriter (tell $ return "Hello" ())
=> ((),"Hello")
```

Comment: `return "Hello" () = "Hello"` because `instance Monad ((->) a) where { return = const; ... }`